# PyCharm not displaying Google style docstrings in tooltips

Tags: python, pycharm, docstring

I would like to use Google style docstrings for Python. I've specified that Pycharm should expect Google docstrings:

[image]

For some reason PyCharm will not show my docstrings in tooltips:

[image]

I'm referencing the examples here for the proper Google docstring format: http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/ext/example_google.html

It's unclear to me why PyCharm is not displaying my docstrings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After contacting JetBrains they notified me that this was a known problem: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/oauth?state=%2Fissue%2FPY-22445

The solution is to update the "pockets" package.

They plan to fix in next release.

Issue is due to using python version 3.6!